# Exception raised when tried to load an image from the Internet

Tags: flutter, image, dart, exception, codec

Tried to use both `NetworkImage` and `Image.network()` methods to load jpg image from the Web, in both cases it says that there is "ImageCodecException" and it's "Fialed to load network image". Tried in DartPad.
This code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      
      home: Scaffold(
        body:
            // Load image from network
            new Image.network(
              'https://www.nasa.gov/images/content/162056main_PIA08329.jpg'),
            ),
   );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first try to wrap your Image.network to Center or something to align Image and the second one is check your url that you provide, you need to provide actual path for that just click to image and simply select "copy image adress" and put it in url. You can also check how to do it here - https://youtu.be/Ln2xvLs6dc4

Comment: Don't think this is the problem, the other image (from documentation's example) works there.

Comment: Then just try to find this image from the other url sometimes this bugs are just happening